# Avoir + participe passé + infinitif

Tags: infinitif

Bonjour. Faut-il écrire "Les choses qu'il a continué de faire" ou "Les choses qu'il a continuées de faire" ? Merci.

Answer (score 5):

« Les choses qu'il a continué de faire » est la forme correcte.

> [accord](https://www.lelivrescolaire.fr/manuel/38/francais-4e/chapitre/384/fiches-de-conjugaison-orthographe/page/692845/le-participe-passe-regles-d-accord-et-cas-complexes/lecon) Le participe passé ne s’accorde pas si le COD du verbe au participe passé n’est pas le sujet de l’infinitif.
>
> - Les feuilles que j’ai vu prendre sont jaunes.
>     Les feuilles sont prises par quelqu’un, elles ne font pas l’action, donc on n’accorde pas le participe passé. « Que » est le COD de prendre et non de « vu ».

Addition suggérée par user **Laurent S.**

> Le participe passé s’accorde si le COD du verbe conjugué est sujet de l’infinitif.
>
> - Les personnes que j’ai vues entrer sont charmantes.
>     Qu’est-ce que que j’ai vu ? les personnes (COD de voir)
>     Qui est entré ? les personnes (sujet de entrer)

*Un exemple de plus*

- Les feuilles que j'ai vues tomber étaient encore vertes. (*même raisonnement que pour l'exemple précédent*)

Comment: Je suggérais d'ajouter un exemple de l'autre type, par exemple : "Les feuilles que je j'ai vues tomber"